# STM32F031 - Code runs in line-by-line debugging but not otherwise. Some functions only run if defined as macros

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f0

I am writing code for the STM32F031K6T6 MCU using the Keil uVision. The IDE information is shown in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK9oY.png)

The C/C++ options for Target are configured as shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZOA.png)

I started a new project, selected the chip, and configured the run-time environment as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDaKy.png)

I initialized the clock and configured the Flash registers for the appropriate latency. I tested the frequency using MCO and it seems correct. I also initialized some GPIOs, UART, and the SysTick. The peripheral registered is modified as expected as seen on the System View for the respective peripheral in the debugging mode.

The problem is that some functions, such as functions for sending and receiving data via UART and some functions that use GPIO ports only work in debugging mode when I run the code line-by-line. If I click the run button the code gets stuck and the chip stops responding. I still see the VAL and CURRENT registers of the SysTick updating.

This is an example of a function that works:

```
void System_Clock_init(void){
            
    FLASH->ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;
    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY | 0x01; 
    
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION;
    while((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY) == 0);
    
    
    RCC->CR &= ~RCC_CR_HSITRIM;
    RCC->CR |= 16UL << 3;
        
    RCC->CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == RCC_CR_PLLRDY);
    
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC;
    RCC->CFGR |= 10UL << 18;
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_HPRE;
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_PPRE;
    
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0);
    
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    
    while((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL);      
}
```

This is an example of a function that doesn’t work:

```
void UV_LED_Driver(uint32_t d){
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i<16; i++){ 
        if(d&(((uint32_t)0x8000)>>i)){
            SDI2_ON;
        }
        else {
            SDI2_OFF;
        }
         CLK2
    }
    LATCH2      
}
```

The macros used in the function above are defined as below:

```
// CLK2 -> PA5
// LE2 -> PA4
// SDI2 -> PA6
#define CLK2_OFF   GPIOA->ODR |= (1UL << 5)
#define CLK2_ON    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1UL << 5)

#define LE2_OFF    GPIOA->ODR |= (1UL << 4)
#define LE2_ON     GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1UL << 4)

#define SDI2_ON    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1UL << 6)
#define SDI2_OFF   GPIOA->ODR |= (1UL << 6)

#define CLK2       {CLK2_ON; us_Delay(1); CLK2_OFF;}
#define LATCH2     {LE2_ON; us_Delay(1); LE2_OFF;}
```

The GPIO pins used in the function above are initialized as follows:

```
// CLK2 -> PA5
// LE2 -> PA4
// SDI2 -> PA6
void UV_LED_Driver_Init(void){
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
    
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~((3UL << 8) | (3UL << 10) | (3UL << 12));
    GPIOA->MODER |=  ((1UL << 8) | (1UL << 10) | (1UL << 12));  
    GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~(0x70UL);
    GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~((1UL << 8) | (1UL << 10) | (1UL << 12));      
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= ~((3UL << 8) | (3UL << 10) | (3UL << 12));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= ((1UL << 8) | (1UL << 10) | (1UL << 12)); 
    GPIOA->ODR |= (0x70UL);
}
```

And the us_Delay() function is based on SysTick. These are defined as:

```
static uint32_t usDelay = 0;

void SysTick_init(uint32_t ticks){
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = ticks - 1;
    NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, (1<<__NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 1);
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    SysTick->CTRL |= SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk;
    SysTick->CTRL |= SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk;
    SysTick->CTRL |= SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;   
}

void SysTick_Handler(void){
    if(usDelay > 0){
        usDelay--;
    }
}

void us_Delay(uint32_t us){
    usDelay = us;
    while(usDelay != 0);
}
```

Now, this is the same UV_LED_Driver(uint32_t d) function defined as a macro (Runs as expected):

```
#define UV_LED_DRIVER(d) {for(int i = 0; i<16; i++){if(d&(0x000F>>i)){SDI2_ON;}else {SDI2_OFF;}CLK2}LATCH2}
```

This is the main():

```
 #include <stm32f031x6.h>
 #include "clock.h"
 #include "LED_Driver.h"
 #include "UART.h"
 
 int main(void){
    
    System_Clock_init();    
    Color_LED_Driver_Init();
    UV_LED_Driver_Init();
    Nucleo_Green_LED_Init();
    UART_init();
    SysTick_init(47);
    //MCO_Init(); // Check PIN 18 (PA8) for the frequency of the MCO using an Oscilloscope  
    while(1){       
 
        UV_LED_DRIVER(~(0x0000)) // This runs well
        //UV_LED_Driver((uint32_t)~(0x0000)); // If I run this line 
        //the debugger gets stuck here. It works if I run line-by-line
        ms_Delay(100);      
        
        UV_LED_DRIVER(~(0xFFFF)) // This runs well 
        //UV_LED_Driver((uint32_t)~(0xFFFF)); // If I run this line 
        //the debugger gets stuck here. It works if I run line-by-line
        ms_Delay(100);
    }           
}
```

Interestingly, if I define the functions as macros, they behave as desired. I finally tested the code on a STM32F429ZIT chip and it worked well, given the needed modifications in the initialization of the main clock and the GPIO.
Has anyone ever experienced anything similar or happens to know what could be causing this issue? I know that I could walk around this issue using CubeMX but I would like to find out what is causing this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried making `usDelay` volatile?

Comment: Function and macro code is not identical.

Comment: There's no such error as "functions stop working". What you describe sounds very much like a stack overflow however. There's a difference between functions and function-like macros, namely the stacking of parameters and return address. If your stack is toast, the _symptom_ occurring when you call a function may be crashes or run-away code etc. So you'll need to monitor the stack to rule out stack overflows before anything else.

Comment: Also please don't invent your own private, evil macro language with abominations like `#define CLK2       {CLK2_ON; us_Delay(1); CLK2_OFF;}`. Either use static inline functions or spell out those items in the macro explicitly. "Do not repeat yourself" is a pox when taken beyond what's reasonable - it causes very bad and dangerous programs. "Keep it simple" wins over "Do not repeat yourself" 10 times out of 10.

Comment: @alagner I haven't tried that initially, but the user that gave me the answer at the ST community forum made the same remark.

Comment: @Armandas Right. But the macro code is how I first wrote the function. I tried changing the types to see if that would be the cause of the problem. But it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question at the ST Community forum and the user *waclawek.jan* answered it. The problem is that I was calling the SysTick interrupt too often, not leaving any time for the main() to run. To fix the code, I just called the SysTick_init() function passing "479" as an argument instead of "47".

Thank you!